# Como faço para enviar uma informação de um ID por e-mail?

Tags: php, formulário, id

Tenho um formulário, nele tem a seguinte linha:

```
<span id="idTaxa"></span>
```

Essa linha carrega os dados da taxa de entrega, até ai tudo bem, mas eu preciso enviar essa informação por e-mail e não estou sabendo fazer.
Para enviar os dados do meu formulário eu uso o método Post, assim:

```
$emporio = $_POST["emporio"];
```

Mas as informações estão em um IMPUT, mas quando tento puxar a informação desse ID (idTaxa) eu não consigo, estou usando essa linha abaixo:

```
$entrega = ["#idTaxa"];
```

Não aparece nada!!! Alguém saberia me dizer qual é a forma certa?
Desde já agradeço a todos

As informações do idTaxa vem do arquivo form.js. Segue abaixo o código:

```
var str = "";
```

var id = "";
var sub = 0.00;
var taxa = 0;
var taxadeentrega = total - taxa;
var total = 0.00;
var qcount = 0;
var scount = 0;
var opc = 0;
var options = "";
for (i=1; i<21; i++){
    options += "" + i + "";
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

```
$( "div div select" ).html(options); 
$( "div div :text" ).attr("value","1");
$( "#btemporio" ).click(function() {
  $( "#emporio" ).css("display","block");
});
$( "#mudaopcao" ).click(function() {
  location.reload(true);
});
function alerta(txt){
    $( "div#alerta" ).html( txt ).show( 0 ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 500 );
}
```

function atencao(txt){
        $( "div#atencao" ).html( txt ).show( 0 ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 500 );
    }
    function mens(){
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getDate() + "|" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "|" + d.getFullYear() + " - " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

```
    $( "div#quentes :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
          if (opc == 4){
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("span").children("select").val();
              str = str + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
          }
          str = str + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=quentes]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#saladas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
          if (opc == 4){
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("span").children("select").val();
              str = str + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
          }
          str = str + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=saladas]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=sobremesas]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#sucos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          var val = $(this).parent().children("input:radio:checked").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + " - " + $(this).parent().children("input:radio:checked").attr("l") + ": R$ " + val.replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (val * sel).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=sucos]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#bebidas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=bebidas]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#sopas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=sopas]').val(str);
    str = "";

    $( "div#emporio :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
          var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
          str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
    })
    $('input[name=emporio]').val(str);
    str = "";

    str = String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
    $('input[name=mtotal]').val(str);
    str = "";

    if(opc==1){
        $('input[name=op]').val("3 Quentes e 3 Saladas");
    }else if(opc==2){
        $('input[name=op]').val("4 Quentes e 4 Saladas");
    }else if(opc==3){
        $('input[name=op]').val("5 Quentes e 5 Saladas");
    }else{
        $('input[name=op]').val("");
    }

    if(opc==0){
        $('input[name=nop]').val("");       
    } else {
        str = "<strong>Opção " + opc + ": </strong>";
        $('input[name=nop]').val(str);
        str = "";
    }

    $('input[name=data]').val(n);
}

  $("div#quentes :checkbox").click(function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
          qcount++;
          if (opc == 1){
              if (qcount == 4){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 3 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  qcount = 3;
              }
              if (qcount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

              }
              if (qcount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

              }
          } else if (opc == 2){
              if (qcount == 5){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 4 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  qcount = 4;
              }
               if (qcount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 pratos quentes");

              }
              if (qcount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

              }
               if (qcount == 3){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

              }
          } else if (opc == 3){
              if (qcount == 6){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 5 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  qcount = 5;
              }
                if (qcount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 4 pratos quentes");

              }
              if (qcount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 pratos quentes");

              }
               if (qcount == 3){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

              }
               if (qcount == 4){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

              }
          }
      } else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
          qcount--;
      }
  })

  $("div#saladas :checkbox").click(function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
          scount++;
          if (opc == 1){
              if (scount == 4){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 3 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  scount = 3;
              }
              if (scount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
              }

          } else if (opc == 2){
              if (scount == 5){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 4 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  scount = 4;
              }
               if (scount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 3){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
              }

          } else if (opc == 3){
              if (scount == 6){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                  atencao("Você só pode escolher 5 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                  scount = 5;
              }
              if (scount == 1){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 4 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 2){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 3){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
              }
              if (scount == 4){
                  $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                  alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
              }
          }
      } else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
          scount--;
      }
  })

  $( ":input" ).click(function() {
  total = 0;
  sub = 0;

  if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).length > 0) {
    $( "#mudaopcao, #titulo2, div#quentes :checkbox, div#saladas :checkbox" ).css("display","inline-block");
    sub += $( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).val() * 1;
    if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 1){
        opc = 1;
        $( "#op2,#op3,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
    } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 2){
        opc = 2;
        $( "#op1,#op3,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
    } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 3){
        opc = 3;
        $( "#op1,#op2,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
    } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 4){
        opc = 4;
        $( "#op1,#op2,#op3,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
        $("div#quentes span, div#saladas span").css("display","inline-block");
        $( "div#quentes :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().find("select").val();
        }) //each quentes
        $( "div#saladas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().find("select").val();
        }) //each saladas
    }
  }

    $( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each sobremesas

    $( "div#sucos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).parent().children( ":radio:checked" ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each sucos

    $( "div#bebidas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each bebidas

    $( "div#sopas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each sopas

    $( "div#emporio :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
        sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
    }) //each emporio

    total += sub;

    //aqui eu pego o cep
```

var cep = document.getElementById("cep").value;

//verifica se deve incrementar ou não
if(cep == "20040-010" || cep == "20071-002" || cep == "20210-010" || cep == "20080-102" || cep == "20230-130" || cep == "20081-250" || cep == "20090-030" || cep == "20090-030" || cep == "20211-340" || cep == "20211-351" || cep == "20221-240" || cep == "20221-250" || cep == "20230-010" || cep == "20230-011" || cep == "20230-025" || cep == "20230-150" || cep == "20230-160" || cep == "20230-240" || cep == "20231-016" || cep == "20231-030" || cep == "20231-031" || cep == "20231-050" || cep == "20231-085" || cep == "20240-180" || cep == "20240-200"){

```
    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 4 no valor final
taxa = 4.0;
```

}if(cep == "20050-091" || cep == "20060-050" || cep == "20071-000" || cep == "20080-003" || cep == "20081-000" || cep == "20081-050" || cep == "20090-000" || cep == "20090-003" || cep == "20231-046" || cep == "20231-047" || cep == "20231-048" || cep == "20231-093"){

```
//se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 3.5 no valor final
taxa = 3.5;
```

}if(cep == "20031-170" || cep == "20040-004" || cep == "20040-020" || cep == "20040-908" || cep == "20071-000" || cep == "20241-180" || cep == "20230-070" || cep == "20230-060"){

```
//se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 3 no valor final
taxa = 3.0;
```

}if(cep == "20010-010" || cep == "20020-906" || cep == "20031-908" || cep == "20031-917" || cep == "20040-001" || cep == "20040-006" || cep == "20050-090" || cep == "20070-022" || cep == "20241-110"){

```
//se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 2.5 no valor final
taxa = 2.5;
```

}if(cep == "20010-020" || cep == "20011-000" || cep == "20011-020" || cep == "20011-030" || cep == "20011-040" || cep == "20011-901" || cep == "20020-000" || cep == "20010-170" || cep == "20011-000" || cep == "20021-260" || cep == "20021-350" || cep == "20031-040" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-130" || cep == "20031-204" || cep == "20040-000" || cep == "20040-003" || cep == "20040-007"){

```
//se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.7 no valor final
taxa = 1.7;
```

}if(cep == "20010-090" || cep == "20020-100" || cep == "20021-130" || cep == "20021-315" || cep == "20030-001" || cep == "20031-000" || cep == "20031-003" || cep == "20031-010" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-141" || cep == "20031-143" || cep == "20031-144"){

```
//se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.2 no valor final
taxa = 1.2;
```

}if(cep == "20020-010" || cep == "20020-040" || cep == "20020-080" || cep == "20021-060" || cep == "20021-120" || cep == "20021-900" || cep == "20021-903" || cep == "20030-002" || cep == "20030-013" || cep == "20030-020" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20030-060" || cep == "20030-070" || cep == "20030-120" || cep == "20030-905"){

```
//se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 0.7 no valor final
taxa = 0.7;
```

}

total += taxa;

if(taxa != 0){
    //caso a taxa seja diferente de 0, mostra ao usuário
    document.getElementById("idTaxa").innerHTML = "Custo adicional: R$" + taxa;
}

```
    $( "div#total" ).html( "Valor total da sua<br>encomenda: R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );
    $( "div#total" ).css("display", "block");
    $( "#total2" ).html( "R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );      
  }) //click
  $( "#total2" ).html( "R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );      


  $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
     if (opc == 4 && (qcount + scount)<6){
        event.preventDefault();
        alerta("Você deve escolher, no mínimo, 6 itens, entre os pratos quentes e saladas");
        return false;
    } else if (total < 17.90){
        event.preventDefault();
        alerta("O valor mínimo do pedido é R$ 17,90");
        return false;
    } else if ($("#nome").val()=="" || $("#endereco").val()=="" || $("#email").val()=="" || $("#cep").val()=="" || $("#telefone").val()==""){
        event.preventDefault();
        alerta("Todos os campos de informação são obrigatórios");
        return false;
    }
    mens();
  }); //form
```

}); // doc ready

Comment: No php vc não puxa as informações pelo atributo `id` da tag mas pelo `name`, sem ele o php não consegue recuperar essa informação. Se pudar colocar a parte do form na pergunta já ajuda.

Comment: Nao tem como pegar direto pelo php com o ID, teria que, no caso, utilizar JS

Comment: Se a informação está dentro da tag você não vai conseguir pegar com php, seria bom voce explicar como a informação da idTaxa é conseguida, pois está muito vago pra passarmos uma possibilidade pra você, nesse caso a única forma de passar isso em um formulario é você criar uma função pra enviar o formulario...e nessa função pegar o conteudo da tag idTaxa com innerHTML e enviar via GET.

Comment: Não conheço nada PHP, mas acho que você está puxando a informação do lugar errado. O seu elemento só existe no lado do cliente e é criado apenas após o render da tela. Além de colocar esse valor na <span> você vai ter que mantê-lo em um input hidden e postá-lo junto para o php.

Caso contrário esse valor é apenas uma informação exibida em tela.

Comment: As informações do idTaxa vem de um arquivo form.js

Comment: No seus inputs vc conseguer se tem o atributo  `name`? para saber os dados enviados no php vc pode fazer `print_r($_POST);` Não precisa postar todo o código apenas as partes relevantes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você obter isso via POST, você precisa enviar através de um formulário. O correto seria você obter o valor desse span de outra maneira, pois o formulário normalmente usamos inputs, selects, checkboxs, etc.

com jquery: **var conteudo = $("#idTaxa").text();** OU **$("#idTaxa").html()** para obter todo o html.

Comment: obter todo o html?

Comment: Sim @durtto, quando você usa .html() você obtem todo o html. Por exemplo, se o idTaxa for assim: <span id="idTaxa"><b>oi</b></span>, você vai obter o <b>oi</b>. Se voce usar o .text(), voce vai obter apenas o texto, nesse caso o "oi".